# Can I remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design from project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design in my asp.net mvc project (.net 6 migrated from .net core 3.1).

This package has a transitive dependency on NuGet.Protocol in a version affected by CVE-2022-41032 (https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-g3q9-xf95-8hp5).

So I'd like to remove the package, but I'm not sure if that has any impact. As far as I understand, the package is necessary for scaffolding. In the project it was used for Identity scaffolding. Once the code is generated and no further scaffolding is needed, is it safe to remove the package?

Answer (score 0):

This package is unfortunately named, it's not actually specific to Visual Studio - it supports scaffolding additional content (like Entity Framework based views and controllers) into projects using the dotnet CLI.

Comment: Thanks, I understood that too. But I'm not sure if you can just remove the package if you don't need code generation anymore. Does already generated code still need the package or does dotnet still need the package for the generated code?

Comment: sorry i don't know that sir